# Generate the same auth token in WebAPI

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

Can I generate the same bearer token from .Net Core WebAPI for debug purposes?

I don't want to authenticate on each API restart, and I'd like to create some statement that would generate the same token if the Debug mode is turned on.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer : no.

The tokens have a duration after which they expire. As such, you cannot generate the same token again.

Protected endpoints / controllers will have the `[Authorize]` attribute on them.

For debug purposes, simply remove it, test to your heart's content then re-add the attribute to enable the authentication system.

If you want piece of mind, you should have integration tests for your endpoints which would work by requesting real tokens.

I like to build postman collections for such things. Couple that with a good logging system for production environments.